# Segmentation fault in unicodedata.category

Tags: python, python-2.7, segmentation-fault

I have two identical server machines. In one of server, I am getting segmentation fault in the following program.

```
import unicodedata
_cat = unicodedata.category(unichr(10614))
```

Both machines use `python 2.7.6` and are Ubuntu 14.04 based server.

This was working fine earlier in the faulty server. It has gone under some maintenance.

Comment: It sounds like something got broken in that maintenance. You might be able to get a clue about the problem by running the script in verbose mode, eg `python -v myscript.py`.

Comment: `python -v myscript.py` is identical upto segmentation fault. I am not able to deduce much from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, filesystem has become read-only after maintenance. As nothing can be written in filesystem, it might be a reason for segmentation fault.